# Instantiate a new class in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I want to send a value from native android to JavaScript. I try like below but i get nullPointerException and i ask this question and a person say to me, i don't should instantiate an activity with new! but i dont know how can solve this and how can i declare this class and how can i call loadUrl() or sendJavascriptInterface() from this class(no main calss, i mean use this methods in new class). I write this code. I know declare a class with new is wrong but i don't know how can solve this! :(

```
public class Test extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.init();
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
Log.e("run javascript func from native android", "");


LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
        0, locationListener);
 }
}
```

GPSLocationListener:

```
public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (location != null) {
    GPScls MyGPS= new GPScls();
    Log.e(""+location.getLatitude(), ""+location.getLongitude());
    MyGPS.GPS(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

}
}

 @Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 }
```

GPScls:

```
public class GPScls extends DroidGap {
public void GPS(double latitude,double longitude) {
super.loadUrl("javascript:GPS("+latitude+","+longitude+");");
//this.sendJavascript("javascript:GPS("+latitude+","+longitude+")");
}
 }
```

I searched around two days but i could not understood :(

Please help me that i can write a correct code!
Thanks for advises

Comment: you can do this with phonegap plugin for android. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

Comment: and If you simply want lat and lon only you cant get by directly javascript

Answer (score 1):

Add parameters in your html file to get desired values. Then add below function in your html script tag to get values from your html url.

```
function getURLParameter(name) 
{
            return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
        }
```

then call getURLParameter in document load to get values

```
var longitude=getURLParameter('longitude');
 var latitude=getURLParameter('latitude');
```

your class

```
public class Test extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.init();
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
        0, locationListener);


        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html?longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude);
Log.e("run javascript func from native android", "");


 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want get GeoLocation from gps android and i have goal, examine how can call and send variable to JS. How can call loadUrl in sencond class not main calss(Test class)?

Comment: if you want to get geolocation then no need to add another class. In phonegap there is api to get geolocation. if u want i can send the code to get geolocation.

Comment: I know have plugin for get lat and long in phonegap. but i want to practice this and for this i want send lat and long by me not use plugin. Thanks if you can help me. I use phonegap 2.9